# How to merge two variables into one in a response?

Tags: azure, rest, web-services, azure-api-management

I have two APIs added to Azure API Management. It's basically the same API, but for different environments. For monitoring purposes, I want to create an operation that would call the same method in both of the APIs and merge their result into one. I currently work on mocked APIs with mocked data.

To achieve that I created a blank API with a blank operation. Inside this operation, I declared the following inbound policies:

```
<inbound>
    <set-variable name="env1" value="" />
    <set-variable name="env2" value="" />
    <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="env1" timeout="20" ignore-error="false">
        <set-url>https://env1-api.azure-api.net/api/data</set-url>
        <set-method>GET</set-method>
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/json</value>
        </set-header>
    </send-request>
    <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="env2" timeout="20" ignore-error="false">
        <set-url>https://env2-api.azure-api.net/api/data</set-url>
        <set-method>GET</set-method>
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/json</value>
        </set-header>
    </send-request>
    <base />
</inbound>
```

When tested the operation called throws 500 (which, I believe, is understandable, as no response is being set). When I look at the Trace tab I can see two messages:

> GET request to 'https://env1-api.azure-api.net/api/data' has been sent, result stored in 'env1' variable.
>
> GET request to 'https://env2-api.azure-api.net/api/data' has been sent, result stored in 'env2' variable.

Based on that I conclude that the calls are working correctly. Here's where I'm stuck. I don't know how to merge those two variables inside a response.

The API's return an array of objects in the form of a JSON object. What I want to achieve is to merge those two responses into one response that will be returned by the operation. How can I compose a response?

Please have in mind that I'm a noob in Azure, so my approach might be too primitive. If you have something better I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to Aleksander's answer, inside the [`return-response` policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#ReturnResponse), there are two ways you can compose the final body

1. Using policy expressions

```cs
<set-body>@{
    var output = new
    {
        success = true,
        var1 = context.Variables["var1"]
    };
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(output);
}</set-body>
```

2. Use liquid templates

```xml
<set-variable name="var1body" value="@((IResponse)context.Variables["var1"]).Body.As<string>())" />
<set-body template="liquid">{
"success": true,
"var1": "{{context.Variables["var1body"]}}"
}</set-body>
```

You can read more about the [`set-body` policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetBody) in its doc.

Comment: This answer lacked only parsing of IResponse :-) `<set-variable name="var1body" value="@((IResponse)context.Variables["var1"]).Body.As<string>())" />` If you would add it, I would accept it as an answer.

Comment: Added that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at return-response policy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#ReturnResponse

Under set-body, you can merge those two strings.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Hi, Aleksandar! Although I noticed "return response" before I kind of did not use it, perhaps because the "aborts pipeline execution" sounded kind of like not the thing I wanted to use. I will try that, but still not sure how to compose to the body.